# Controlling dplyr evaluation scope with mutate_each_

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to ensure `mutate_each_` (or maybe it is `funs_`) looks for functions in the parent frame?  Consider:

```
library(dplyr)    # 0.4.1
library(magrittr) # 1.5

fun_list <- list(a=quote(rev), b=quote(sort))
iris[1:5, 1:2] %>% mutate_each_(funs_(fun_list), c("Sepal.Length"))
```

Works as you would expect:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width   a   b
1          5.1         3.5 5.0 4.6
2          4.9         3.0 4.6 4.7
3          4.7         3.2 4.7 4.9
4          4.6         3.1 4.9 5.0
5          5.0         3.6 5.1 5.1
```

But:

```
my_rev <- rev
my_srt <- sort
fun_list2 <- list(a=quote(my_rev), b=quote(my_srt))
iris[1:5, 1:2] %>% mutate_each_(funs_(fun_list2), c("Sepal.Length"))
```

Errors with:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : could not find function "my_rev"
```

A simple `mutate` works:

```
iris[1:5, 1:2] %>% mutate(a=my_rev(Sepal.Length), b=my_srt(Sepal.Length))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the formula `~` notation here instead of `quote()`

```
my_rev <- rev
my_srt <- sort
fun_list2 <- list(a = ~my_rev, b = ~my_srt)
iris[1:5, 1:2] %>% mutate_each_(funs_(fun_list2), c("Sepal.Length"))
```

From the Non-standard evaluation vignette:

> It’s best to use a formula, because a formula captures both the
>   expression to evaluate, and the environment in which it should be a
>   evaluated.